# Does Google Dart have something like regex.exec()?

Tags: dart

I read the documentation (https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.1/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) but could not find I was looking for. Either I didnt understand it or I overlooked something.

I am trying to replicate the following in google dart:

```
var regex = /foo_(\d+)/g,
    str = "text foo_123 more text foo_456 foo_789 end text",
    match = null;

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match); // matched capture groups
    console.log(match.index); // index of where match starts in string
    console.log(regex.lastIndex); // index of where match ends in string
}
```

I also created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h3z88udz/

Does dart have something like regex exec()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RegExp.allMatches` looks like it does what you want.

```
var regex = new RegExp(r"foo_(\d+)");
var str = "text foo_123 more text foo_456 foo_789 end text";

void main() {
  for (var match in regex.allMatches(str)) {
    print(match);
    print(match.start);
    print(match.end);
  }
}
```

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/dd1c136fa49ada4f2ad4ffc0659aab51

Comment: Thanks it works! I just saw the list of methods includes Group() and Groups() which both accept an integer.